# Can a web server infer the user's ISP?

Tags: http, ip, webserver

Is it possible for a web server to infer the user's **ISP** reliably?

Note: I'm **not** interested in the IP or the geo-location, just the ISP.

It would be OK if this worked only for a restricted region, i.e. only for users from one specific country.

Comment: Are you familiar with ookla speed test?

Comment: No. How would a speed test be of any help?

Comment: Try googling it, see what you get

Comment: Interesting! But it looks like I'll have to check the terms of use carefully. Maybe this will do, but I wonder if there's also a method that does not require a 3rd party service.